# Is getUserMedia microphone streaming not fully implemented on chrome for android?

Tags: web-audio-api, getusermedia

When run on Chrome for Android (29.0.1547.72 on a Nexus 4 with 4.3.0) getUserMedia just returns 0's in the stream buffer when set to audio. i.e. it's not capturing the mic audio.

Is this yet to be fully implemented, or is it an error?

An example can be seen using this demo site: http://learnwithecho.com/testaudio.html

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We now have Web Audio input working in Chrome for Android Beta (31.0.1650.11).

Comment: Thanks. Is it imminent?

Comment: Also, [this WebRTC example](https://apprtc.appspot.com/) allows the microphone to work in Chrome for Android, and it appears to use getUserMedia. Is there a way to go via this method to access local microphones?

Comment: Actually, we now have Web Audio input working in _Beta_ Chrome for Android!  Revising answer.

Comment: (We just didn't have the Web Audio stream hookup working for a while.)

Comment: Fantastic! It seems like it works great on the Nexus 4. Really responsive and low latency. Thank you!

Comment: I just tried the [WebRTC example](https://apprtc.appspot.com/?r=41748578) given by @Ian above. It does not work for me in current Chrome (release version) on Android. I get "Failed to access local media ... PermissionDeniedError". Is that expected? Am I missing somethning?

Comment: hmm.  That should work... any more info on your version/device?